# C++ object life scope

Tags: c++, object, lifecycle

I seem to have misinterpreted the life scope of objects in c++. If you'd consider the following:

```
class MyClass{
public:
    int classValue;
    MyClass(int value){
        classValue = value;
    }
    static MyClass getMyClass(int value){
        MyClass m1 = MyClass(value);
        return m1;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass m1 = MyClass(3);

    cout << m1.classValue << endl;
    m1 = MyClass::getMyClass(4);
    cout << m1.classValue << endl;    

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
3
4
```

And I thought, that when m1 gets a non-dynamic object, that has been created 'on the stack' of getMyClass function, me trying to get a value from it wouldn't work, because the object would be dead. Could someone enlighten me? Do not spare me any details!

Comment: The sample code does not even compile. main() attempts to instantiate MyClass using the default constructor, which is not declared. I won't even mention the obvious bug in the constructor that the class does have. Voting to close this question as a typo.

Comment: It seems like you misunderstood "class". Maybe I am wrong but I dont see why you would really need a class for that.

Comment: Yeah.. sorry bout that.. has more stuff in there and didnt delete it properly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And I thought, that when m1 gets a non-dynamic object, that has been created 'on the stack' of getMyClass function, me trying to get a value from it wouldn't work, because the object would be dead. Could someone enlighten me? Do not spare me any details!

There is a bit of misunderstanding.

Yes, the object is created on the stack in `getMyClass`.
Yes, the object is dead when the function returns.

However, the line:

```
m1 = MyClass::getMyClass(4);
```

assigns the return value of the function to `m1` before the object is dead. The object lives long enough to allow the run time to complete the assignment.

BTW, the line

```
MyClass m1;
```

is not right since `MyClass` does not have a default constructor. You can replace the lines

```
MyClass m1;
m1.value = 3;
```

by just the one liner

```
MyClass m1(3);
```

**Update**

You need to change the constructor of `MyClass`.

```
MyClass(int value){
    value = value; // This does not initialize the
                   // member variable of the class.
                   // The argument shadows the member variable.
}
```

Use:

```
MyClass(int valueIn) : value(valueIn) {}
```

Comment: `MyClass m1(3);` will have a problem too: `value = value;` in constructor :)

Comment: @RSahu thank you for replying :) what I still dont get, is that from my point of view, the object I return is out of scope right after I return and assign it, so how does m1 still have that object stored in it? Is that a copy of the object?

Comment: @Jakub, `m1` does not have that object. The object gets assigned to `m1`. It's no different than `int a = 10;`. `10` is a temporary object that gets assigned to to `a`.

Comment: @RSahu OK let me try to say what I think I understand now :) even though the object itself is out of scope when I return from the function, since it is an object I am returning I get a copy of it? thanks a lot